# SQL DB2 Union skip NULL/0 rows

Tags: sql, null, db2, union

Is there an easy way to skip NULL rows in union?
I am on DB2.

Example:

```
SELECT 'FIRST', sum(value) FROM  SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION
SELECT 'SECOND', sum(value) FROM  SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION
SELECT 'THIRD', sum(value) FROM  SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

result:

```
1---------|2-----
    FIRST   1
    SECOND  NULL/0
    THIRD   3
```

So, if one of the unions has 0 or NULL it should be skipped:

Estimated example result:

```
1---------|2-----
    FIRST   1
    THIRD   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by checking for `IS NOT NULL` using a `HAVING` filter.

```
SELECT 'FIRST', sum(value)
    FROM  SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 GROUP BY 'FIRST' HAVING sum(value) IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT 'SECOND', sum(value)
    FROM  SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 GROUP BY 'SECOND' HAVING sum(value) IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT 'THIRD', sum(value)
    FROM  SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 GROUP BY 'THIRD' HAVING sum(value) IS NOT NULL
```

If any of the `sum(value)`s return `NULL`, the associated `SELECT` statement will return zero rows due to the `GROUP BY` clause, resulting in the corresponding row omission.

If you want to omit a row based on *either* a `NULL` *or* a zero sum, add an `AND` conjunction like thus:

```
SELECT 'FIRST', sum(value) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 GROUP BY 'FIRST' HAVING sum(value) IS NOT NULL AND NOT sum(value) = 0
UNION
SELECT 'SECOND', sum(value) FROM  SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 GROUP BY 'SECOND' HAVING sum(value) IS NOT NULL AND NOT sum(value) = 0
UNION
SELECT 'THIRD', sum(value) FROM  SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 GROUP BY 'THIRD' HAVING sum(value) IS NOT NULL AND NOT sum(value) = 0
```

In addition, you can increase your query's likely efficiency by changing `UNION` to `UNION ALL` because you will not ever have duplicate rows in your final result. `UNION` does a duplicate check which in this case will never trigger.

Answer (score 4):

Use a subquery.  I would also suggest `union all`:

```
SELECT col, val
FROM (SELECT 'FIRST' as col, sum(value) as val FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'SECOND' as col, sum(value) as val FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'THIRD' as col, sum(value) as val FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
     ) t
WHERE val IS NOT NULL AND val > 0;
```

Notes:

- `UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  Use `UNION ALL` to avoid that overhead.
- The comparison `val IS NOT NULL` is redundant.  But it explicitly expressions the conditions you want.

Comment: thank you, it works perfect!, but for my query, the solution below is better to implement.

Comment: @user982998 . . . Sure.  I would think that having the condition only once would be simpler, but your situation might be different.